# Rails hidden_field name

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hidden-field

I have such code:

```
= hidden_field(:user_id, nil, :value => params[:user_id])
```

But it is generating such html:

```
<input id="user_id_" name="user_id[]" type="hidden" value="1">
```

But what i need to write, to generate such html code:

```
<input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value="1">
```

Without any arrays? Also, if i write only one input, without any form tags, will i see this value in params, or i must to write full: form_tag, then there hidden field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hidden_field_tag

```
hidden_field_tag 'user_id', 1
# => <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value="1" />
```